# My DAG config/params aren't being passed to my task

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I am passing some run-time DAG params/config to a `PythonOperator` in a very similar way to [these Airflow docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.4/concepts/params.html):

```py
def print_x(x):
    print(f"x is {x}")


with DAG(
    "print_x",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 6, 15, tz="UTC"),
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    params={
        "x": Param(42),
    },
) as dag:
    PythonOperator(
        task_id="print_x",
        op_kwargs={
            "x": "{{ params.x }}",
        },
        python_callable=print_x,
    )
```

But when I manually trigger the DAG I always get the default value (42) regardless of what I put into the "Trigger DAG" dialog box.

What's going wrong here?

*Note: In my particular case I'm running Airflow 2.2.2 on AWS Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA) but I don't think that should be relevant.*

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [little discussed param](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dag-run-conf-overrides-params) which controls whether config passed when triggering DAGs gets used in the DagRun's tasks:

At the bottom of the [Params concepts page](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.4/concepts/params.html#disabling-runtime-param-modification) it says (the emphasis is mine):

> The ability to update params while triggering a DAG depends on the flag core.dag_run_conf_overrides_params. **Setting this config to False will effectively turn your default params into constants.**

On MWAA it seems like this is set to `False` by default. You can see whether this is the problem by the message you get at the bottom of the "Trigger DAG" page:

> As `core.dag_run_conf_overrides_params` is set to `False`, so passing any configuration here won't override task params.

[image: Trigger DAG dialog]

Comment: In other words, when MWAA states "All Airflow configuration options are using default values." for a given environment, that doesn't mean the configuration parameters are using the default values as specified by the Airflow docs for that version of Airflow!

Comment: Thanks for this. This begs the question: what's the use for this config parameter, why would you be using params at all when this config option is set to false?